# Amazon Echo censors SSML output

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit, ssml

I was trying to let my AlexaSkill give out some phrases, but it censors the letter combination 'zob' to 'z**'

The JSON-Output looks normal, but the output itself is changed. 
Is there any chance to let it pronounce correctly? I didn't find a explanation for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language is this? In French, at least, *zob* is slang for a part of the male anatomy, and it's likely that Amazon is preventing Alexa from swearing (as it does in all languages) to "protect the brand."

You might be able to use IPA to say that without censoring, but it's also likely that it will be caught in certification and rejected.